# LaTeX3 Regex using control sequence

Tags: macros, latex3, l3regex

I'd like replace some words/characters using l3regex on a arbitrary variable.

Instead of doing this

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_myname_tl {Hello}
\regex_replace_all:nnN {(\w+)} {\1 World!} \l_myname_tl
```

which works, I'd like to do something like that

```
\def\myname{tmpname}
\cs_new_protected:cpn { l_\myname _tl } {Hello}
\regex_replace_all:nnN {(\w+)} {\1 World!} \use:c {l_\myname _tl}
```

I've an error saying I've an extra parenthesis }. I'm not very familiar with LaTeX3 but If I understand well, the problem comes from the `\use:c {l_myname _tl}` not considered as an single token (no braced) as expected by `:nnN`.

What is the way of doing that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a variant:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_replace_all:nnN { nnc }
```

so you can call

```
\tl_set:cn { l_ \myname _tl } {Hello}
\regex_replace_all:nnc {(\w+)} {\1 World!} {l_ \myname _tl}
```